# Remove list of strings from list of strings

Tags: string, list, kotlin

I have a long list of strings (the main list), and a short list of strings. The short list is an exclude list, and I want to remove all occurences of the elements in the exclude list from the main list.

I've found these two ways of doing it, but none of them seem to work:

```
val fnrliste: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

val excludeList = listOf("28030140259", "12050101833", "21089233132", "12050101833")

//Alternative 1:
for (fnr in excludeList) { fnrliste.remove(fnr) }

//Alternative 2:
fnrliste.removeAll(excludeList)
```

With both alternatives, the strings in the entries are still there when I list the contents of fnrliste.

As can be seen in this screenshot, some entries have been removed (different result with the two methods), but the first entry in the exclude list is still present:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `fnrliste` contains some duplicates, so that's why you get different result. Also, as far as I can remember your screenshot, in case of `removeAll` the first element is `"28030140259 "` and not `"28030140259"` so everything is correct